# Create an a multi diemensional array from different variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do i create a multi-dimensional array from different javascript variables ?

For example, i have these three variables

```
var pdate = "|2019-12-26|2019-12-26|2019-12-26"
var products_id = "3354|5009|61927"
var products_category =  "ENERGETICS|CASIO|SEIKO"
```

And i would like to transform them into this

```
var products_list = []
[0] = {pdate:"2019-12-26",products_id:"3354",products_category:"ENERGETICS"}
[1] = {pdate":"2019-12-26",products_id:"5009",products_category:"CASIO"}
[2] = {pdate:"2019-12-26",products_id:"61927",products_category:"SEIKO"}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Use `split()` to split the strings into arrays. Then loop over them and create an array of objects.

Comment: Why does `pdate` have a delimiter at the beginning, but the other strings don't?

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array. It's a 1-dimensional array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function split to separate the datas:

```js
var pdate = "2019-12-26|2019-12-26|2019-12-26";
var products_id = "3354|5009|61927";
var products_category = "ENERGETICS|CASIO|SEIKO";

var arrayPdate = getData(pdate);
var arrayProducts_id = getData(products_id);
var arrayProducts_category = getData(products_category);
var result = []
for (let i = 0; i < arrayPdate.length; i++) {
  let jsonObject = {
    pdate: arrayPdate[i],
    products_id: arrayProducts_id[i],
    products_category: arrayProducts_category[i]
  }
  result.push(jsonObject)
}
console.log(result);

function getData(c) {
  return c.split("|")
}
```

Comment: I think getData(c) is only redundant split wrapper leading for larger complexity IMO

Answer (score 0):

You need use `.split` function on your string and then use loop with array index for others.

```js
var pdate = "2019-12-26|2019-12-26|2019-12-26";
var products_id = "3354|5009|61927";
var products_category =  "ENERGETICS|CASIO|SEIKO";

pdate = pdate.split('|');
products_id = products_id.split('|');
products_category = products_category.split('|');

let arr = [];
for(let i=0; i<pdate.length; i++) {
  arr.push({
    pdate: pdate[i],
    products_id: products_id[i],
    products_category: products_category[i] 
  });
}

console.log(arr);
```